# Refresh element(without ajax call)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

There is element:

```
#profile_search_bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 0;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-color: #f7f7fe;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;

}
```

It is placed on the bottom of the page and it works for me, until one JS function is called, which extends page content (nothing else matters here).

And extending page with full reload actually would place this element as it needed, but as it AJAX action, this element stays were it was, and now it is in the middle of the page.

I want just to reload it, and here is no need, I suppose, in AJAX, coz I just need to tell browser:"Hey, friend, you've already loaded element, can't you just notice, that page content was extended".

Comment: What do you mean by "reload" or "refresh" if not "fetch content from the server?"

Comment: Give a `position:fixed` if it always has to stay at the screen bottom,no matter what content is loaded

Comment: @MattBall, I need browser to consider previous AJAX change, but not to load this element with reques againg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe try adding a simple function to the AJAX code. When the infomation is fetched and updated try this:

```
$("#profile_search_bottom").css({"bottom":"10px"});
```

It actually depends on the browser you are using, but i hope this works for you.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
}).done(function( ) {
  //your stuff here
  $("#profile_search_bottom").css({"bottom":"10px"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your element on your first AJAX call. i.e. 'ajax-fetched'

In your AJAX query, check first if element has ajax-fetched class:

```
if $('your_element').hasClass('ajax-fetched')
  <<< your logic here >>>
else
  << your ajax request >>>
  on success: $('your_element').addClass('ajax-fetched')
end
```

It sounds to me as the easiest approach. Yet with more details on your side we could easily come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function(){
    $('#profile_search_bottom').css('bottom', '10px');
});
```

Probably just an issue with positioning on scroll, and when the window resizes.